# return list of records with different filters on single search button

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have used different search buttons but i want the same functionality which can be done with the help of single search button

also i type any matching string with the record name then it should return the list
i.e. if there is a record with name 'laptop' then if i enter the l or lap or laptop then it should return the record with name laptop

VF Page--

```
<apex:page controller="searchcontrol">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputText value="{!nameString}" label="Search By Name" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!SearchByName}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!emailString}" label="Search By Seller Email" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!SearchByEmail}" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!priceString}" label="Search By Price" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!SearchByPrice}" />
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Mlist}" var="mer">
                    <apex:column value="{!mer.name}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!mer.Merchandise_Price__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!mer.Merchandise_Qunatity__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!mer.Merchandise_Size__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!mer.Seller_Email__c}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller--

```
public class searchcontrol {
    public String nameString {get;set;}
    public String emailString {get;set;}
    public Integer priceString {get;set;}
    public list < Merchandise__c > Mlist {get;set;}
    public searchcontrol() {
        Mlist = new list < Merchandise__c > ();
    }
    public void SearchByName() {
        Mlist = new list < Merchandise__c > ();
        // String val='\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(nameString.trim()) + '%\'';
        Mlist = [Select id, name, Merchandise_Price__c, Merchandise_Qunatity__c, Merchandise_Size__c, Seller_Email__c, Merchandise_Description__c from Merchandise__c where name =: nameString];
    }
    public void SearchByEmail() {
        Mlist = new list < Merchandise__c > ();
        Mlist = [Select id, name, Merchandise_Price__c, Merchandise_Qunatity__c, Merchandise_Size__c, Seller_Email__c, Merchandise_Description__c from Merchandise__c where Seller_Email__c =: emailString];
    }
    public void SearchByPrice() {
        Mlist = new list < Merchandise__c > ();
        Mlist = [Select id, name, Merchandise_Price__c, Merchandise_Qunatity__c, Merchandise_Size__c, Seller_Email__c, Merchandise_Description__c from Merchandise__c where Merchandise_Price__c =: priceString];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Dynamic SOQL and read some documentations https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by a function similar to below:

```
public void search(){
    Mlist = new list < Merchandise__c > ();
    if(nameString!=null && nameString.trim()!='') || (emailString!=null && emailString.trim()!='') || (priceString!=null && priceString.trim()!='')){
        String query='Select id, name, Merchandise_Price__c, Merchandise_Qunatity__c, Merchandise_Size__c, Seller_Email__c, Merchandise_Description__c from Merchandise__c where'
        if(nameString!=null && nameString.trim()!='')
           query+='name like \'%'+nameString+'%\' ';
        if((nameString!=null && nameString.trim()!='') && (emailString!=null && emailString.trim()!='') )
           query+=' and ';
        if(emailString!=null && emailString.trim()!='')
           query+='Seller_Email__c = \''+emailString+'\' ';
        if((emailString!=null && emailString.trim()!='') && (priceString!=null && priceString.trim()!='') )|| ((nameString!=null && nameString.trim()!='') && (priceString!=null && priceString.trim()!=''))
           query+=' and ';
        if(priceString!=null && priceString.trim()!='')
           query+='Merchandise_Price__c = '+priceString+' ';
        Mlist=(list < Merchandise__c >)Database.query(query);
        }
    }
```

where search would be a common function called from all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the single search function below to perform a search by all inputted fields.

```
public void doSearch(){
    String query = 'Select id, name, Merchandise_Price__c, Merchandise_Qunatity__c, Merchandise_Size__c, Seller_Email__c, Merchandise_Description__c from Merchandise__c where FILTER_GROUP';

    String filter = '';

    emailString = String.escapeSingleQuotes(emailString);
    if(String.isBlank(emailString) == false){
        if(String.isBlank(filter)){
            filter += ' Seller_Email__c LIKE \'' + emailString + '%\'';
        }
    }

    nameString= String.escapeSingleQuotes(nameString);
    if(String.isBlank(nameString) == false){
        if(String.isBlank(filter)){
            filter += ' name  LIKE \'' + nameString + '%\'';
        }else{
            filter += ' AND name LIKE \'' + nameString + '%\'';
        }
    }

    if(priceString != null){
        if(String.isBlank(filter)){
            filter += ' Merchandise_Price__c = ' + priceString;
        }else{
            filter += ' AND Merchandise_Price__c = ' + priceString;
        }
    }

    if(String.isBlank(filter)){
        filter = 'Id != \'\'';
    }

    query = query.replace('FILTER_GROUP', filter);
    Mlist= (List<Merchandise__c>) Database.query(query)
}
```